# Ubuntu 16.04 Live-USB Casper Partition

Tags: live-usb, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

I had no issues with this in 15.04 or 15.10, so I suspect this is new to 16.04.

I have frequently used the Universal USB Installer to create Live USBs with a casper-rw file for persistence. Once two of them are made, I boot to one, plug in the other, and resize the 2nd to make room for a casper-rw partition larger than 4gb.  Then I delete the casper-rw file in the primary installation partition.  This then allows the Live USB to have larger than 4gb persistent storage.

I have performed this *successfully a great many times* with Ubuntu ***15.04*** and ***15.10***.

**That said, when I do this with 16.04 it breaks the Live installation.  It will no longer boot.  Has the process changed?**

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to use persistent partitions, (casper-rw or home-rw), with SDC or Unetbootin installs of 64bit post 12.04 Ubuntu.

The persistent partitions do work if I make the drive using a grub2/iso install using MultiBootUSB. I understand mkusb also works.

With 16.04 I can not even get the drive to show in gparted to make the casper-rw partition.